# formatting of text in p tag not formatting?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, datatable

Evening all...User enters data into a record which is stored in the DB. If I copy the text from this record into note pad it is displayed formatted correctly...

```
    Drive along the coastline and drink in the sights exploring the newly-designated Wild Atlantic Way where secrets lie hidden in remote peninsulas. And on the mountain roads, the sweet aroma of turf smoke will greet you as you make your way around.

The county can justifiably make many claims: the highest sea cliffs and the largest sand dunes in Europe, the biggest waves in Ireland. With no fewer than 13 unspoilt golden strands, it proudly boasts the largest number of Blue Flag beaches of any county in Ireland.

Where, the visitor may ask, is the essence of Donegal? There is not one particular spot since it is to be found everywhere: from the burstingly fresh local seafood, at the summit of Errigal mountain, in the Killybegs fishing boats bringing home the catch, in the ruins of a medieval castle, on a ferry ride to Tory Island, on top of an ancient hillfort, or in the reminiscent <br/> call of the corncrake or shrill whistle of the oystercatcher.
```

However when displaying on screen in the browser I put the text inside a `<p>` tag but it displays on screen as...

```
Drive along the coastline and drink in<br /> the sights exploring the newly-designated Wild Atlantic Way where secrets lie hidden in remote peninsulas. And on the mountain roads, the sweet aroma of turf smoke will greet you as you make your way around. The county can justifiably make many claims: the highest sea cliffs and the largest sand dunes in Europe, the biggest waves in Ireland. With no fewer than 13 unspoilt golden strands, it proudly boasts the largest number of Blue Flag beaches of any county in Ireland.Where, the visitor may ask, is the essence of Donegal? There is not one particular spot since it is to be found everywhere: from the burstingly fresh local seafood, at the summit of Errigal mountain, in the Killybegs fishing boats bringing home the catch, in the ruins of a medieval castle, on a ferry ride to Tory Island, on top of an ancient hillfort, or in the reminiscent <br/> call of the corncrake or shrill whistle of the oystercatcher.
```

As you can see no formatting, line spaces after paragraphs etc...does anyone know why? thanks

code that renders the html....

```
//mvc dataTable being displayed
     <p>@row["Description"]</p>
```

Comment: please show code that renders the html

Comment: @John — It isn't possible to vote to close without giving a reason. Swearing at us isn't going to encourage us to help you.

Comment: Use a `<pre>` tag instead of the `<p>`. HTML ignores the end of line.

Comment: What MVC framework are you using to retrieve the data and render the view? Chances are you need to convert line breaks to <br> tags.

Comment: thanks for replies I am using Version=4.0.0.1 and I tried <pre> tag adds extra line between each sentence but also increases the size of the image which isnt inside a pre text but is inside the same div as the <pre> tag <div><img></img><pre></pre></div>

Comment: Alternatively try adding `white-space: pre-line` to the css for the containing `<p>` this will make the text wrap on line breaks (and when necessary as per default)

Comment: @cfreear ahh yes...Nice 1...thanks for the help man. Stick the Q on il mark it as an answer

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment on OP:

You can use `white-space: pre-line` on the containing element to wrap on all line breaks and as per default white space rules (wrapping on white space to fill element).